# How to find all comparison from a large set of data set

Tags: r, loops

I have a large data set from an experiment. There are about 25000 spectrum in the data set. I want to see if there is any common feature in all spectrum. There is a builtin function for comparespectra between two specific spectra. But I want to develop a loop that gives me results from all possible comparison. Finally, want to make a data.frame or list along with the identity of the compared spectrum number.

I wrote a simple loop that gives me a comparison of spectrum 1 and 2, 2 and 3, 3 and 4 and 4 and 5.

```
for (i in 1:4){
   comparison <- compareSpectra(raw_25kda[[i]], raw_25kda[[i+1]], fun = "common")
   print(as.list(comparison))
}
```

From the loop, I have the list of 4 number 2,5,6,2 respectively for four comparisons of 1 and 2, 2 and 3, 3 and 4 and 4 and 5 comparisons.

The first comparison is between 1 and 2 and there is 2 common feature. Is there any way I can explicitly print that 1 and 2 are compared and there is 2 common feature between them?

I also want a comparison of 1 and 3, 1 and 4, 2 and 4, 3 and 4 as well.

When I recall comparison later in different R chunk that gives me only one value such as the last value 2. How can I save the list inside the loop for future analysis? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is a little hard to follow, but even more difficult to really test without sample data. I wonder, is it necessary to use your actual "large" dataset? I suspect you could resolve this with `expand.grid` or `outer` to determine all pairwise combinations for comparisons, then wrap that in a loop (or `Map` or `lapply`) to save the results. But it's a bit difficult to demonstrate clearly to you without a good sample dataset.

Comment: Presumably you are using the `MSnbase` package? You should note the use of any non-base R packages by including `library()` calls in your code so that others can load the same functions you're looking at.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the data or packages you are using, so this might be a little off, but should hopefully point in the right direction.

Here are all the combinations of 5 data sets:

```
my_data_sets <- 1:5
combos <- combn(my_data_sets, m = 2, simplify = T)
combos
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#[1,]    1    1    1    1    2    2    2    3    3     4
#[2,]    2    3    4    5    3    4    5    4    5     5
```

There are 10. Now we can initialize a list with ten elements to store our results in.

```
combo_len = dim(combos)[2]
output <- vector("list", combo_len)
for (i in combo_len) {
  set1 = combos[1, i]
  set2 = combos[2, i]
  output[[i]] <- compareSpectra(raw_25kda[[set1]], raw_25kda[[set2]], fun = "common")
}
```

The `output` object should now have ten elements which each represent their respective combination.